# how to take screen shot of camera view controller iOS using objective-c

Tags: screen

In my app I display the camera and I am taking screenshots of certain perts using UIGetScreenImage, (I tried UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext and it works great for screenshots on almost any part of my app but for the camera view it will just return a blank white image) ...